# database dataSize in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

With following command, I can get the data size of a specific collection:

```
db.collection.dataSize()
```

How do I get the datasize of a database?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use following command at mongoshell:

```
 db.stats()
```

Output should be like this:

```
{
  "collections" : 3,
  "objects" : 80614,
  "dataSize" : 21069700,
  "storageSize" : 39845376,
  "numExtents" : 9,
  "indexes" : 2,
  "indexSize" : 6012928,
  "ok" : 1
}
```

See more diagnostic command [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics).

Comment: What type are the datasize and storagesize numbers in?

Comment: The dataSize and storageSize are in bytes.  See - [sizing and trimming](https://www.compose.com/articles/sizing-and-trimming-your-mongodb/)

Comment: I know this question is old. REALLY old but is there a way to insert these results into a different collection ? I would like to run this every day to measure the database growth.

Answer (score 4):

Use db.getStats() in Java

```
CommandResult re = db.getStats();
for(String k: re.keySet()){
    System.out.println(k+"="+re.get(k) );
}
```

Then will get result like below:

```
serverUsed=127.0.0.1:27017
db=test
collections=3
objects=100004
avgObjSize=67.99876004959802
dataSize=6800148
storageSize=10633216
numExtents=9
indexes=1
indexSize=4406864
fileSize=50331648
nsSizeMB=16
ok=1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

The [dbStats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#output) command returns different storage statistics for a given database. 
As explained in [this post](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-mongodb-performance-metrics-mmap/) about the different MongoDB performance metrics you should monitor (with MMAPv1), the `dataSize` metric that you mentioned measures the space taken by all the documents and padding in the database. 
To get the "storage footprint" of you database on disk, you should look at the `fileSize` metrics which corresponds to the size of your data files. It decreases only if you delete a database and is not affected when collections, documents, or indexes are removed.

Here is a diagram with the different important storage metrics returned by dbStats:
[image]

Also note that, with the MMAPv1 storage engine, the mapped memory (`mem.mapped` metric), corresponding to the quantity of virtual memory used to map the database into memory, gives you a good approximation of the total size of your database(s). You can access this metric with the [serverStatus command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverstatus.mem.mapped).

Answer (score 1):

**In MongoDB :**

```
db.stats()         //For db status
db.<collectionname>.stats() //For collection status
```

**In Python :**

```
connection = pymongo.Connection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 27017)
db = connection["test_db"]
test_collection = db["test_collection"]
db.command("dbstats") # prints database stats for "test_db"
db.command("collstats", "test_collection") # prints collection-level stats for "test_collection" under "test_db".
```

**In PHP :**

```
$con= new Mongo()

$stats=$con->dbName->command(array('dbStats' => 1));  // for db.stats()

$stats=$con->dbName->command(array('collStats' => 'collection_name')); // for db.collection_name.stats()
```